# prove that a particular set is open

Tags: analysis

Let $S= \{(x,y): y<2x+1\}$.Then prove that $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

To prove that we must show that

> for every $(u,v)\in S $ there exists $r>0$ such that the ball $B[(u,v),r]$ is contained in $S$

Or, equivalently,

> For all $(u,v)$ such that $v<2u+1$ there exists $r>0$ such that:
>   for all $(x,y)$, $\sqrt{(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2}<r\Longrightarrow y<2x+1$

How do we prove that inequality?

Answer (score 4):

$f(x,y)=2x+1-y$ the set is $f^{-1}(]0,+\infty[)$ and is open since $f$ is continue and the inverse image of an open set by a continuous map is open.

Comment: the right choice.

Comment: Nice solution! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take $\vec{u} = (u,v)$ in $S$ and name $l$ the line of equation $y = 2x + 1$ you can define $2r = dist((u,v),l)$, since $\mathcal{B}(\vec{u},r) \subset \mathcal{B}(\vec{u},2r) \subset S$ you have proved that for each $\vec{u} \in S$ you can find the $r > 0$ such that $\mathcal{B}(\vec{u},r) \in S$. I think the inclusion $\mathcal{B}(\vec{u},2r) \subset S$ is trivial. It's a geometric construction the mine.